# Azure Devops hide key columns on deployment of SSAS Tabular model

Tags: azure-devops, sql-server-2017, ssas-tabular

I would like to have all columns of my SSAS Tabular model visible in our DEV environment. As I don't want to show key columns, I would like to automatically hide those columns in an Azure Devops release pipeline to the TST environment. Is it possible to alter the tabular .bim file in such a way during deployment?

Everything we use is on premises.

Johan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We use TabularEditor in our pipeline to deploy the model, where in the process we make some in fly changes.

TabularEditor support Csharp scripting (where you can manipulate properties of all partitions / Tables / Columns). That means you can switch columns' visibility for example.

Here You can find all supported flags:
https://github.com/otykier/TabularEditor/wiki/Command-line-Options

I recommend the fourth video (pipeline deployment):
https://github.com/otykier/TabularEditor/wiki/Training-Webinar-for-Tabular-Editor